# PHP date format question

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to format some dates in PHP (i'm a Coldfusion programmer, so the syntax is similar, but i'm stuck!).

The dates are formatting perfectly into the display I want. However, they all return 1st Jan 1970.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

For background, I am pulling a date from a datetime column in mySQL. The raw date i'm trying to format is....

2010-04-03 00:00:00

Here is the line of code i'm using....

```
$xml_output .= "\t\t<eventdate>" . date("l jS F", $row['event_date']) . "</eventdate>\n";
```

I want it to display as: Saturday 3rd April

Any help would be appreciated!

Simon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second parameter to `date()` needs to be a [**UNIX timestamp**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_timestamp).

Convert your date string it into a timestamp first using `strtotime()`:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($row["event_date"]);
echo date("l jS F", $timestamp); // Saturday 3rd April
```

Manual pages:

- [**date()**](http://www.php.net/date)
- [**strtotime()**](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: You forgot to pass `$timestamp` as an argument to `date()`

Answer (score 2):

The [`date`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function works with an [UNIX timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) *(i.e. a number of seconds since January 1, 1970)*, and not a date passed as a string.

This means you have to first convert your date to a timestamp, using [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), for instance :

```
$timestamp = strtotime('2010-04-03 00:00:00');
```

And, then, you can use the `date` function on this timestamp :

```
echo date('l jS F', $timestamp);
```

Which gets you the output you wanted :

```
Saturday 3rd April
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could let MySQL [format the date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for you on retrieval (makes for cleaner code in building your XML):

```
SELECT
  event_date,
  DATE_FORMAT( event_date, '%W %D %M' ) AS event_date_formatted
FROM
  ...
```

Then in PHP:

```
$xml_output .= "\t\t<eventdate>" . $row['event_date_formatted'] . "</eventdate>\n";
```

Also:
MySQL date formatting functions are a bit more flexible, as they don't depend on unix timestamps that much (if you use DATETIME fields, that is). Admittedly a bit unlikely perhaps; but if your event_date exceeds the unsigned 32 bit integer timestamp boundaries, your pretty much screwed with php's `date` function. Try formatting a date before January 1st 1970, or after January 19th 2038, and you will see what I mean.

Comment: awesome, that'll probably be a lot faster for the result return. i'll give that a go! the fix above for the unix timestamps has fixed the issue anyway. But I'd sooner have the sexier dates straight out of mySQL :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `strftime()` function to convert the datetime you get from a database in a unix timestamp suitable for `date()`:

```
date("l jS F", strtotime($row['event_date']))
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP date function expects to receive a unix timestamp.

Change the format of the date you pull from the db to unix timestamp.